# How to access an object within another object with empty braces (no dots inside) with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, joomla

This code

```
console.log(window.Joomla.editors);
console.log(window.Joomla.editors.instances);
console.log(window.Joomla.editors.instances.jform_core);
```

shows me this:
[image]

I do not understand why `window.Joomla.editors.instances.jform_core` is `undefined`. The only difference I can see is that there are three dots in the braces of `window.Joomla.editors`. And no dots for `window.Joomla.editors.instances`. How can I access `window.Joomla.editors.instances.jform_core`?

Comment: JSON.stringify(window.Joomla.editors.instances) might help you figure out what's going on.

Comment: What you see in console is not a snapshot it is a live object. If you can't access the property it means it hasn't been added yet

Comment: could you please share and dummy JSON Object

Answer (score 3):

`{...}` means that the object has some properties. `{}` is an empty object. Therefore when you logged it, it had no proerties at all. The properties you see in the unfolded menu is the live view of the object, so the properties were added after you logged and before viewing the logs.

To resolve this you have to access the properties after they were added, maybe `window.onload` does help.